# DFS Replication Manager on Failover Cluster Nodes

Tags: windows, cluster, replication, failover, dfs

I currently have a VM architecture setup for high availability / manageability.
The one point of failure is that I have a single windows 2008 machine that runs DFS replication across the servers in my web server farm.

I am upgrading the virtual environment to 2012 and I would like to use a windows failover cluster in place of the single machine. Can I run the DFS replication manager on the nodes of the cluster? All the info I find is about adding the cluster to a DFS replication set and I dont want to do that. I want to replicate the shared local storage of each web server node so the cluster does not store the data it just manages the syncing.

Also, if there is a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish please let me know.

Keep in mind that I would also like to use the cluster for a SQL AOG setup too, so thats why I was thinking I could kill two birds with one stone by running DFS on it as well.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: What do you mean by `I have a single windows 2008 machine that runs DFS replication across the servers in my web server farm.`. Either you have a DFS-R (consisting of multiple servers) or you haven't. But one server alone is not a DFS-R?

Comment: Thanks for responding, sorry I didnt get an email notification of your comment. What I mean is I have a server that has a DFS-R service running that syncs two other server's network shares on my web servers. So the server running the DFS-R is not participating in the replication itself it is only managing the replication of other machines.

Answer (score 1):

DFS and DFS-R is not a solution to implement high availability.

If you want to have highly available network shares, implement a SMB failover.

Find some more information at http://blogs.technet.com/b/clausjor/archive/2012/06/07/smb-transparent-failover-making-file-shares-continuously-available.aspx